# Craft 3 Session Ended modal popping up on local machine

Tags: craft3, session, mamp

- Using MAMP Pro 5.1
- Apache, self-signed SSL cert
- PHP 7.2.8 module mode

  - OPcache enabcled
  - Extensions: Xdebug, Imagick/ImageMagick
- Craft 3.1.22

Basically I'm having the same problem as tons of other posts here, I keep getting the session ended popup in the cpanel frequently but refreshing the page still has me logged in.

While some posts seem to have solutions here for craft 2, I've tried to replicated them on craft 3 where I could but it's not working. I've tried:

- deleting storage/runtime/*
- clearing all cookies, local storage, etc
- restarting apache
- using MAMP PROs Memcached instance and adding this to `app.php`

```
'components' => [
            'cache' => [
                'class' => yii\caching\MemCache::class,
                'useMemcached' => true,
                'defaultDuration' => 86400,
                'servers' => [
                    [
                        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                        'persistent' => true,
                        'port' => 11211,
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

- a variety of combinations of these settings in `general.php`

```
'useSecureCookies' => false
'requireMatchingUserAgentForSession' => false,
'requireUserAgentAndIpForSession' => false,
'defaultCookieDomain' => '.proposify.local',
'rememberedUserSessionDuration' => 999999,
'userSessionDuration' => 0
```

- session.auto_start = 0 set in php.ini

When I'm in the CPanel I see this request in the network tab, which as soon as the response comes back pops up the session expired popup:

```
https://myLocalDevDomain.com/index.php?p=admin/actions/users/get-remaining-session-time&dontExtendSession=1
```

which returns this:

```
{"timeout":0,"csrfTokenValue":"..."}
```

I've currently set chrome to block this request and am not getting the popup but this is of course not a great solution.

Comment: Check the value of the `CraftSessionId` cookie in the browser's console. Does it keep changing if you keep reloading the page?

Comment: it stays the same

Comment: Any related errors in the Craft `storage/logs` folder or messages about authentication/being logged out?

Comment: none at all, and I'm not getting logged out, if I refresh the page I'm still logged in.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior across multiple browsers?

Comment: I did until yesterday (most recent chrome, FF). I've now gone a day and a half without any modal popups without changing anything in craft or browsers.

Comment: Yay computers!!